# Do you earn more rewards for playing on a higher difficulty level?

Tags: attack-on-titan-2

In Attack on Titan 2, the player is presented with three different difficulty level: Easy, Medium, and Hard. So my question is, do you earn more rewards for playing on a higher difficulty level?

If so, what is the difference in materials, funds, or other rewards and are there materials that are locked to higher difficulty levels?

I haven't been able to find any information regarding this topic for Attack on Titan 2, only [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/179664-attack-on-titan/74246539) thread for Attack on Titan.

Comment: Also, is anyone with > 1500 rep able to add an Attack on Titan 2 tag? Probably under attack-on-titan-2, I would but I don't have the ability yet.

Comment: Got you covered.